# instantiateViewController throws SIGABRT on Unit Test

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm writing unit tests for a controller that has elements (like buttons) created in storyboard. I'm trying to instantiate the view controller in my Unit Test so I can access those elements and not have the app crash. However, the way that I am trying to instantiate my storyboard is causing Xcode to throw a SIGABRT error on the line that I am calling the `instantiateViewController` command.

This is the code that I am using to try and instantiate my storyboard in my unit test file:

```
func testAreaActionsViewController() {

       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder))
       let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AreaActionsViewController") as! AreaActionsViewController


//        view.loadView()
//
//        view.viewDidLoad()




}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why it is throwing SIGABRT? I verified in my storyboard that the Identifier is AreaActionsViewController, and also set the target in my Main.storyboard to include my testing target.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late but I had same issue and I solved removing this:

```swift
@testable import ProjectName
```